# Binding in triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

Я описую шаблон для кнопки, хочу чтобы цвет кнопки при наведении и в нормальном состоянии задавался пользователем. Но при установке тригерров мне выдает ошибку "The member "RelativeSource" is not recognized or is not accessible". Как исправить?

```
<Window x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.MainWindowView"
        x:ClassModifier="internal"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.Controls"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="Expense Traker"
        Height="500"
        Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBackground" Color="#FF5FB860"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverBackground" Color="#FF509A50"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:RoundButton}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Height="30"
                    x:Name="border"
                    BorderThickness="2">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding MouseOverBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="border"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <controls:RoundButton Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
                          Background="{StaticResource NormalBackground}"
                          MouseOverBackground="{StaticResource MouseOverBackground}">
    </controls:RoundButton>
</Window>
```

И сам класс:

```
internal sealed class RoundButton :Button
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MouseOverBackground", 
        typeof(SolidColorBrush), 
        typeof(RoundButton), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public SolidColorBrush MouseOverBackground
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Больше похоже на что-то вроде опечатки, но все равно написал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, что научились составлять [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), отвечать стало гораздо проще и приятнее!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [классе `TemplateBindingExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.templatebindingextension(v=vs.110).aspx) отсутствует свойство `RelativeSource`. Используйте обычный `Binding` (`TemplateBinding` нельзя использовать в триггере):

```
<Setter Property="Background"
        Value="{Binding MouseOverBackground,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        TargetName="border"/>
```